# Accessing JSON value with unique named subarrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I want to sort a JSON array based on time value in a subarray with the key names of the subarrays being named uniquely.

I'm searching for the method to access key, value update_time of every element in Products so I can use that value in a sorting script.

I have tried sorting the array but can not determine how to access the key, values of the subarrays

Expected behavior should be that every `unique_keyname_#` element is available for sorting and is sorted for further processing in JavaScript. Ultimately with the newest `unique_keyname_#` as the first element in a list, based on the update_time key.

```
var obj = {
  "company": {
    "department_1": {
      "Products": {
        "unique_keyname_1": {
          "product_owner": "co-worker-1",
          "update_time": "unix_timestamp_1"
        },
        "unique_keyname_5": {
          "product_owner": "co-worker-4",
          "update_time": "unix_timestamp_45"
        },
        "unique_keyname_8": {
          "product_owner": "co-worker-2",
          "update_time": "unix_timestamp_5"
        }
      }
    },
    "department_2": {
      "Products": {
        "unique_keyname_3": {
          "product_owner": "co-worker-1",
          "update_time": "unix_timestamp_21"
        },
        "unique_keyname_6": {
          "product_owner": "co-worker-2",
          "update_time": "unix_timestamp_7"
        },
        "unique_keyname_4": {
          "product_owner": "co-worker-3",
          "update_time": "unix_timestamp_75"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no array in your JSON?!

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Do you have control over how that JSON is generated? The structure is pretty illogical, something like this would be easier to traverse: `{"company": { "departments: [{ Products: [{ "product_owner": "foo" }] }]  } }`

Comment: Don't snippet code that doesn't run. If the OP adds what he attempted, we can always convert it to a snippet.

Comment: @cerbrus Thanks for your response. I do not have control over the generated JSON. This is a thrid party response ro a GET request. I will attempt to rewrite the response with some code into a more appropiate response. 
I was already doubting the structure logic and that put off finding a good way to work with it. Thanks for establishing my doubt as valid!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by writing an intermediate script in python which makes the API response a valid array. From there it was fairly easy to sort the data.

Thanks for the replies confirming the data itself was deliverd to me in an inappropriate format!

regards

Answer (score -2):

In your example, there are no arrays. 
Anyway, in Javascript you can access a node using `.`  like:

```
 obj.company.department_1.Products.unique_keyname_1
```

Or using `[]` which gives you more freedom to use costume fields

```
 obj["company"]["department_1"]["Products"]["unique_keyname_1"]
// can also be more dynamic as:
 obj["company"]["department_"+ department_counter]["Products"]["unique_keyname_" + keyname_counter]
```

Is there a possibility that you will change the structure of your JSON? to make it more manangeable ?

if so, i would recommend the folowing structure:

```
var products = [
  {
    department: 'SomeDepartment',
    productName: 'Something',
    productOwner: 'Someone',
    update_time: 'Sometime'
  }
]
```

Then you can sort the array easy using `Array.sort()`
for the sort topic use this : [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: This solution relies on the amount of departments being known.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Cerbrus. But - it depends only on the products.
Then you can sort by departments, and sub-sort by whatever.

Comment: Did you see the key names for products? `unique_keyname_3`, `unique_keyname_6`, `unique_keyname_4`... If you don't know these Ids before-hand, there's not much you can do with this answer.